# Выпадающее меню

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вот код:

```
<tr>
<td class="tabright">Страны:</td>
<td class="tableft"><select id="tmode" onchange="worktimechange(this.from); return false;">
<option value="0">Россия</option>
<option value="1">Белоруссия</option>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr id="worktimeline" style="display: none;">
<td class="tabright">Город</td>
<td class="tableft"><select id="inter">
<option value="1">Минск</option>
<option value="2">Могилев</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
```

Вот обработчик:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){ 
function worktimechange(frm) {
if (???????.value > 0) {
document.getElementById('worktimeline').style.disp lay = '';
} else {
document.getElementById('worktimeline').style.disp lay = 'none';
}
return false;
}
</script>
```

Что поставить вместо `???????`, чтобы при выборе "Россия" в выпадающем меню выпадающее меню "Город" не появлялось, а при выборе "Белоруссия" выпадающее меню "Город" появлялось.

**Подскажите пожалуйста как это осуществить на старой версии jquery-2.0.3**

Comment: @droget, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @droget, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вы подключили JQuery и не используете его возможностей) [Вот тут накидано решение](http://jsfiddle.net/a941p0dk/)

HTML

```
<select id="tmode">
<option value="0">Россия</option>
<option value="1">Белоруссия</option>
</select>

<select id="inter">
<option value="1">Минск</option>
<option value="2">Могилев</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
#inter {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('#tmode').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).val()>0) {
        $('#inter').show();
    } else {
        $('#inter').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это осуществить на старой версии jquery-2.0.3?